# Ubuntu 9.10/Gnome: Rename filesystem under "Computer"?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, filesystems, rename

On my laptop running Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic) I have a 100 GB fat32 partition listed in `/etc/fstab` to be mounted at `/media/shared`. In Gnome, this filesystem shows up on my desktop and under "Computer" as "100 GB Filesystem". How can I rename it's icon to say "Shared" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using GParted?  I don't have a fat32 partition, but I did load up GParted and with my ntfs partition unmounted I can change the label via right-click and selecting **Label**. (for NTFS this requires having ntfsprogs installed as well)

GParted is in the repos easily installed from the termial:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `nautilus`, the default file manager for ubuntu, does not support renaming of labels. Following this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive) you should be able to do it via command line or, as already suggested, using `gparted`.